# What is the purpose of message handler INT_PTR return value?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, winapi, visual-c++

I was playing with visual studio's windows forms and the example code had this:

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    /*code cut*/
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
    break;
```

While my other handler function looks like this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    /*code cut*/
    return 0; // no magical casting or anything, just plain int
```

I have a clue that in WndProc() when i do a `return 0;` it means the message wont get handled by the default message handler? but if you do `return 1;` it would handle with default handler?

But what is the point of `return (INT_PTR)TRUE;` ? and is it safe to use plain `return 0;` style there? i tried to compile and it works with just plain integer values too.

Also, im not sure when i should use which of the values, the example code had this:

```
EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
```

But what is the point of the `return (INT_PTR)TRUE;` there? I changed it to `FALSE` but couldnt see any difference in functionality.

So, im not sure what this is doing, could anyone clear my mind on this, when should i use `return 1` and when should i use `return 0`, and when should i use something else (if i should) ?

Comment: I doubt very much that you were playing with WinForms and came across this code -- WinForms is a .NET-based framework.

Comment: @ildjarn, i wrote there "windows-forms" but this site renamed it to "winforms" for some reason. i also wondered why it did that, i thought its just another alias for it so i didnt bother changing it (if its even possible...), is "windows-forms" even the right name for this?

Comment: "WinForms" is just a common abbreviation for "Windows Forms", but again, Windows Forms is a .NET technology and this is clearly native C++. This is typically referred to as WinAPI code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first piece of code is a DialogProc -- quoting [the relevant docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645469%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> **Return Value**
>   Type: `INT_PTR`
>   Typically, the dialog box procedure should return `TRUE` if it processed the message, and `FALSE` if it did not. If the dialog box procedure returns `FALSE`, the dialog manager performs the default dialog operation in response to the message.

The second piece of code is a WindowProc -- quoting [the relevant docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633573%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> **Return Value**
>   Type: `LRESULT`
>   The return value is the result of the message processing and depends on the message sent.

So, that `/*code cut*/` part is critically relevant, because which return value you want depends entirely on which message is being handled.

Comment: oh i see, so its not as simple as i thought.

Answer (score 1):

They're somewhat the same. `LRESULT` is intended to be a return value type that can hold something at least the size of a pointer on a given platform.

From [Windows Data Types (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

**LRESULT**:
*Signed result of message processing.*
*This type is declared in WinDef.h as follows:*

```
typedef LONG_PTR LRESULT;
```

**LONG_PTR**:
*A signed long type for pointer precision. Use when casting a pointer to a long to perform pointer arithmetic.*
*This type is declared in <BaseTsd.h> as follows:*

```
#if defined(_WIN64)
 typedef __int64 LONG_PTR; 
#else
 typedef long LONG_PTR;
#endif
```

The `LRESULT` type has gone through a number of changes over the years. I believe prior to Win64, it was defined as `INT_PTR`, but then updated for portability under Win64. A number of other types went through similar changes, such as `WPARAM` and `LPARAM`, which used to be 16 bit values in Win16, are 32 bit values in Win32, and are now 64 bit in Win64.

The actual value returned varies depending on the windows message context, as @ildjarn pointed out. There's also a chance the example source that you're reading was probably created before Win64 became a big deal, and may not have been updated or checked for portability since it was written.

For portability, the symbols are defined slightly differently depending on compile target. Hence, `(INT_PTR)TRUE` is better even if you know the exact value that should be returned that happens to match your build. While `return 0;` may return the correct result in cases where the return value is empty, this is bad form when compiling under scenarios where portability matters. Using `return -1;` or even `return 0x7FFFFFFF;` is even worse, as you may truncate, mask, or otherwise mangle the response that should be given for all platform compile targets.

Using the predefined symbols and constants is best, as the correct values and types will be substituted in for you as you change your compile targets.

Comment: I think the question was less about the types and more about the values.

Comment: The values are meant to be opaque; even though there really aren't that many cases where a `1` and a `0` wouldn't map to the correct values per platform target. I admit, this is splitting hairs now, but a decade or more ago it was a big deal with Win64 on the horizon. Also, these semantics are still a big deal for anyone who is in the habit of writing platform-portable C.

Comment: I meant that I think the OP was asking why `TRUE` was being returned in one case and (effectively) `FALSE` in the other.

Comment: The question title perhaps implies the rather broader context of the difference in the usage of `(INT_PTR)TRUE` or `(INT_PTR)1` as opposed to just `TRUE` or `1`, or even `(INT_PTR)FALSE` or `(INT_PTR)0` as opposed to `FALSE`, or `0`. It turns out that `(LRESULT)` can be interchanged with `(INT_PTR)` in either a _WindowProc_ or a _DialogProc_, as at least verified by this [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/rules-for-using-pointers).